# How to convert multiple files with Winff?

Tags: ffmpeg, convert, winff

When I select one file to convert from ".mpg" format to ".mp4" format in Winff, it converts nice! but when I try to convert many ".mpg" files, I see only one file in output folder! and guess Winff always rewrite on it!...How I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with WinFF, but, in general,

`for i in *.mpg ; do

    j=${i%%.mpg}

    j="${j}.mp4"

    WinFF $i $j

done`

should do the trick.

Be sure to run this the first time with 'echo WinFF' in place of 'WinFF' to see what commands will be generated.